# error return while WCF service trying insert records to sql server using EF 6

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I have service that **500 to 1000** client call it at **every 3 sec**,that means we have **100K** to **1M** record each min ! 
the service have to inserting a record to MSSQL server for each request,but some times when EF try to insert a record another instance insert it at the same time of this instance,this will make a error on inserting for second instance

what is the best practice for handling this problem.
I think using the *SP* will take care of this,but i'm not sure

Comment: Just on a side note I think you will struggle to get that kind of throughput to a single table in SQL. Do you have the locking turned off for SQL as this may be why you are getting errors on insert

Comment: yes i do.but the error still exist